# Storing access and refresh token in python self.sessions doesn't work

Tags: python, azure, session, active-directory, refresh-token

I am currently developing integration for users and groups through Azure AD. I have set up everything to retrieve an access and refresh token upon login, I am only having trouble storing both of them in the sessions. I am assigning the tokens to a session and trying to retrieve them as shown below.

```
self.session["access_token"] = json.dumps(access_token)
self.session["refresh_token"] = json.dumps(refresh_token)
```

then I am fetching both tokens on another page, using

```
access_token = json.loads(self.session.get('access_token'))
refresh_token = json.loads(self.session.get('refresh_token'))
```

I can only for some reason get the access_token inside the other page, the refresh token is always None. For reference I am using the BaseHandler module on both pages.I was thinking of storing both in the database being a solution, but I want to know if it is possible to configure it in some way to work with self.session. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: The refresh tokens are acquired only when the access token is getting/get expired that's the reason the refresh token is always showing you as null.

Comment: I get the refresh token from the response from azure on the first page, the problem is when I try to access it through self.session.get on the second page...

Comment: Hi @azivk Sorry for the delay in responce. did the issue resolved for you are still looking for any help on this.?

Comment: Hi @Raghavendra-MSFTIdentity, we have implemented a workaround for this but it isn't perfect. Would be great if you could advise a better solution for us to implement, since the load time with our current implementation is taking longer than what we wanted.